# Delete Local User Profiles with suffix _Inactive

Tags: powershell

I want to delete local user profiles from C:\Users as well as the registry on a great number of machines in my company.

The practice for some time has been to rename the user profile folders in C:\Users from just the username to username_Inactive

I would like to simply run this script:

```
$profilesToDelete = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | where {$_.LocalPath -match '_Inactive'} -ErrorAction Stop

    foreach ($profileToDelete in $profilesToDelete)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Removing Profile $($profileToDelete.LocalPath) & Associated Registry Keys on $env:COMPUTERNAME..."

        Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $profileToDelete -ErrorAction Stop
    }​
```

However.... the local path for each win32_userprofile does not reflect the manual profile folder name change from username to username_Inactive

I can use this script to show me a list of all the user profiles named username_Inactive by running:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\" | Where {$_.Name -match '_Inactive'}​
```

But I'm kind of at a loss at this point as how to move forward. I have some ideas but not enough technical know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's *a* solution that will correlate the paths and neatly deal with the `LocalPath` business:

```
$inactiveList = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*_Inactive').FullName -replace '_inactive$'
$deleteList = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile).Where{$PSItem.LocalPath -in $inactiveList}

foreach ($delete in $deleteList) {
    Write-Verbose "Removing profile '$($delete.LocalPath)' and associated registry keys on $Env:COMPUTERNAME."
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath "$($delete.LocalPath)_Inactive" -NewName $delete.LocalPath -Force
    $delete | Remove-WmiObject
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DRuppe If this answered your question, kindly mark it as the answer ✅